# Different definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, continuity

**Condition**: $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is continuous. For any countable sequence of pairwise disjoint sub-intervals $(x_k, y_k)$ of $I$, we have $\forall\epsilon\exists\delta$ such that $$ \sum_{k} |y_{k} - x_{k}| < \delta$$
implies 
$$\sum_{k} |f(y_{k}) - f(x_{k})| < \epsilon.$$

Is this condition a necessary or sufficient condition of absolution continuity? Note that the order of the logic identifiers has changed.

> A function $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous on an interval $I$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever a **finite** sequence of pairwise disjoint sub-intervals $(x_k, y_k)$ of $I$ satisfies
>   $$ \sum_{k} |y_{k} - x_{k}| < \delta$$
>   then 
>   $$\sum_{k} |f(y_{k}) - f(x_{k})| < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any function $f:I\to\mathbb R$ (not necessarily continuous), the condition:  For any countable sequence of pairwise disjoint sub-intervals $(x_k, y_k)$ of $I$, we have $\forall\epsilon\exists\delta$ such that $$ \sum_{k} |y_{k} - x_{k}| < \delta$$
implies 
$$\sum_{k} |f(y_{k}) - f(x_{k})| < \epsilon$$
is trivially true.

**Proof:** Given any countable sequence of pairwise disjoint sub-intervals $(x_k, y_k)$ of $I$, just choose $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k} |y_{k} - x_{k}|$.  Then the condition $ \sum_{k} |y_{k} - x_{k}| < \delta$ will be false and so the implication "$ \sum_{k} |y_{k} - x_{k}| < \delta$
implies 
$\sum_{k} |f(y_{k}) - f(x_{k})| < \epsilon$" will be trivially true.

So this conditionis not sufficient for absolute continuity or even continuity.

Comment: Yes, I also saw this after you gave the detailed explanation in the other question

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are equivalent. Suppose you choose $\delta$ according to the usual definition of absolute continuity with $\epsilon$ repalced by $\epsilon /2$. If $(a_k.b_k)$ is  a disjoint sequence of interval with total length less than  $\delta$ then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |f(b_k)-f(a_k)| < \epsilon /2$ for each $N$. Let $N \to \infty$ to complete the proof.

Comment: Many thanks for your teaching! So you proved that the definition "$\forall\epsilon\exists\delta(\forall \text{finite subintervals we have} (\sum|y_k-x_k|<\delta \Rightarrow \sum|f(y_k)-f(x_k)|<\epsilon))$" is equivalent to "$\forall\epsilon\exists\delta(\forall \text{countable subintervals we have} (\sum|y_k-x_k|<\delta \Rightarrow \sum|f(y_k)-f(x_k)|<\epsilon))$". However, my first condition means "$\forall \text{countable subintervals}(\forall\epsilon\exists\delta \text{we have} (\sum|y_k-x_k|<\delta \Rightarrow \sum|f(y_k)-f(x_k)|<\epsilon))$". Not sure my understanding is correct, though.